# How do I make pointers compatible in a new struct?

Tags: c, struct, gtk, typedef

I am trying 'inherit' a GtkWidget. I could inherit any other widget like GtkWindow etc and implement its methods in its own file. I am then going to load the new widget with a function which returns the widget like so `return g_object_new(...`.

The code works fine but I get ***incompatible pointer type*** warning in the struct init function.

> class.h

```
#ifndef CLASS_H_INCLUDED
#define CLASS_H_INCLUDED

#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#define CLASS_NAME_TYPE (class_name_get_type())
G_DECLARE_FINAL_TYPE(ClassName, class_name, CLASS, NAME, GtkWidget)

ClassName *class_name_new();

#endif // CLASS_H_INCLUDED
```

> class.c

```
#include "class.h"

struct _ClassName
{
  GtkWidget parent;
};

G_DEFINE_TYPE(ClassName, class_name, GTK_TYPE_WIDGET);

static void class_name_init(ClassName *self)
{
    gtk_widget_set_name(self, "Widget");
}

static void class_name_class_init(ClassNameClass *klass)
{

}

ClassName *class_name_new()
{
    return g_object_new(CLASS_NAME_TYPE, /* "foo", bar ,*/ NULL);
}
```

In the function `static void class_name_init(ClassName *self)`, I want to use the pointer **self** like so

```
gtk_widget_set_name(self, "Widget");
```

This is where I have compatible pointer type. gtk_widget_set_name() is expecting a type **GtkWidget** as an input but the init function has the type **ClassName**.

Gtk knows ClassName is the same type as GtkWidget hence the code works but is there anyway to fix the code so that the compiler doesn't think its a mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you should use cast operator to avoid compiler warnings, assuming that self is a pointer:

```
gtk_widget_set_name((GtkWidget*)self, "Widget");
```

Answer (score 1):

Defining the object also works like so `GTK_WIDGET(obj)`

Instead of

```
gtk_widget_set_name(self, "Widget");
```

do

```
gtk_widget_set_name(GTK_WIDGET(self), "Widget");`
```

You can always define the object if self is a window `GTK_WINDOW(self)`